# When record source of my form in MS Access is on SQL Server, view is not updatable

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have set record source of my form to a SQL Server view. Now when I open that

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDocuments", WhereCondition:=varWhere
Forms!frmDocuments.SetFocus
```

it will be opened but it is not updatable. I would like to know, is this normal? Every view we open in Access form is not updatable.

I read on the net if I create unique index for view it will be updatable.

Now when I try to create index on view with this code

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX i_Documents 
    ON qryDocuments([Owner Document Number])
```

I get an error

> "schema bound"

Then I try create view with schema binding, I get error

> Cannot schema bind view 'test' because name 'tblDiscipline' is invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself.

The code I have used is like below:

```
CREATE VIEW qryDocuments 
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS  
    SELECT 
        tblDocuments.[Owner Document Number], tblDocuments.[Sazeh Document 
   Number], 
        tblDocuments.[Document Title], tblDocuments.[Project No], 
        tblDocuments.Originator, tblOriginator.[Originator Des], 
        tblDocuments.Zone, tblDocuments.Unit, tblDocuments.Discipline, 
        tblDiscipline.DiscDesc, tblDocuments.[Document Type],  
        tblDocumentType.[TYPE Description], tblDocuments.SheetNumber
    FROM 
        tblDiscipline 
    RIGHT JOIN 
        ((tblDocumentType 
    RIGHT JOIN 
        tblDocuments ON tblDocumentType.TYPE = tblDocuments.[Document Type]) 
    LEFT JOIN 
        tblOriginator ON tblDocuments.Originator = tblOriginator.Originator)  
        ON tblDiscipline.DiscCode = tblDocuments.Discipline
  GO
```

Please help - how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a little bit of formatting to that wall of text query. Notice how I used alises which reduces the amount of code considerably and makes it a lot easier to see what is going on. Those joins are something else. Combing right and left join in such a pattern kind of indicates this was written by a query tool.

```
SELECT d.[Owner Document Number]
    , d.[Sazeh Document Number]
    , d.[Document Title]
    , d.[Project No]
    , d.Originator
    , o.[Originator Des]
    , d.Zone
    , d.Unit
    , d.Discipline
    , dis.DiscDesc
    , d.[Document Type]
    , dt.[TYPE Description]
    , d.SheetNumber
FROM tblDiscipline dis
RIGHT JOIN tblDocuments d ON dis.DiscCode = d.Discipline
RIGHT JOIN tblDocumentType dt ON dt.TYPE = d.[Document Type]
LEFT JOIN tblOriginator o ON d.Originator = o.Originator
```

Now that you can actually read this query the error message is quite clear. Look specifically at this part. "Names must be in two-part format". You cannot schema bind a view when you don't specify the schema of the objects. You probably need to take a look at the documentation here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql Look specifically at the portion about "Updatable Views".

Comment: thanks, the previouse problem solved but i got error "for view with outer join can not create index it must be inner join" now i change to inner join and can update query in my form. but i have a question there is no way for creating index on view with outer join?

Comment: No it can't have an outer join. Think about that for a second. You would be asking the query engine to update a row in your view but the column you are updating doesn't actually exist because it is in the table that if from the table in the left join. You should again look at the documentation when trying to do things. Here is the documentation for creating indexed views. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views